# Highlight simple button in openui5

Tags: sapui5

```
var oToolbar = new sap.ui.commons.Toolbar({standalone: false, design: sap.ui.commons.ToolbarDesign.Standard}).addStyleClass("uiActionToolbar"),

oToolbar.addItem(new sap.ui.commons.Button({text: "Key equipment(LIVE)", styled: false, lite: true, icon:"sap-icon://email",
                        //pressed:true,
                        //style: sap.ui.commons.ButtonStyle.Emph,
                        press:function(oEvent){
                              oAppContainer.addPage(oPage1);
                              oAppContainer.to(globalId+"page1");
                        }
                    })),
oToolbar.addItem(new sap.ui.commons.Button({text: "Key equipment", styled: false, lite: true, icon:"sap-icon://email",
                        //pressed: false,
                        //style: sap.ui.commons.ButtonStyle.Emph,
                        press:function(oEvent){
                              oAppContainer.addPage(oPage2);
                              oAppContainer.to(globalId+"page1");
                        }}))
```

As per above code there are 2 buttons in a toolbar I wanted to show them highlighted when selected for which I have added:

```
//pressed:true,
//style: sap.ui.commons.ButtonStyle.Emph,
```

But neither of them seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Just set `styled` property to `true` and `lite` property to `false` or remove them at all and update the button's style after the `press` event occurs:

```js
oToolbar.addItem(new sap.ui.commons.Button({
    text: "Key equipment(LIVE)", 
    styled: true, 
    lite: false, 
    icon:"sap-icon://email",
    press:function(oEvent){
        if(this.getStyle() === "Default"){
            this.setStyle("Emph");
        }else{
            this.setStyle("Default");
        }
        oAppContainer.addPage(oPage1);
        oAppContainer.to(globalId+"page1");
    }
}));
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/biloheline/1/edit?html,output) is an example.

Comment: `styled: true, lite: false` is actually the default.. so I'd suggest removing these settings entirely for cleaner code.

Comment: @Marc Maybe for some unknown reason the topic starter needs them:-D But you're right, that's why I suggested the option to remove them at all.

Comment: Sry, was blind.. just looked at the code, not the text ;)

Answer (score 0):

For sap.m.Button, use type="Transparent" (or "Default") and type="Emphasized".